# Login failed for user using tedious

Tags: node.js, sql-server, npm, authentication, tedious

I am using tedious to connect to SQL Server Express, but I get a login failed error.

Server browser and SQL Server service are running, TCP/IP is enabled in network protocol. User name is enabled moreover I am able to login with .NET code but node.js code is really not working for me

```js
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

  var Request = require('tedious').Request;  
  var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;
  var Tedious = require('tedious');  
  var config = {  
      userName: 'sa',  
      password: 'password',  
      server: 'localhost',  
      options: {
          encrypt: true, 
          database: 'MediWorks', 
          instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS01'
        },
      port : '1433'  
  };  
  var connection = new Tedious.Connection(config);  

  connection.on('connect', function(err) {  
    if (err)
        {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Connected");  
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why is the instance name `SQLEXPRESS01` ? Did you specifically name your SQL Server Express instance `SQLEXPRESS01`? If not: the **default** - if you didn't specify anything - is just `SQLEXPRESS` - have you tried that? Also - not sure what tedious expects - but typically, you have to provide server and instance name in one place - you you would need to use `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` or `machine-name\SQLEXPRESS` - not just `SQLEXPRESS`

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information, tedious has deprecated the way you use config. A working example is like the following:

```
var config = {
    server: "localhost",
    authentication: {
        type: "default",
        options: {
            userName: "yourusername",
            password: "yourpassword"
       }
    },
 };
```

[tedious Github issue that mentions this.](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/890#issuecomment-482299898)